# queue locking up with multiple threads

Tags: c++, queue, c++17

I am trying to implement a thread safe queue using the  include in c++17. Few notes: uint8_t is purposely used instead of a boolean. MultiQueue is just a template because I need to hold 3 different types within my program so instead of writing 3 different functions for each type i used a template. All of this is stored in a file called queue_safe.h
Problem: The queue class seems to be locking up and doing absolutely nothing and timing out THEN instead of returning it executes the code  under this comment /* if a timeout was not hit, but the queue was empty previously this will execute */. This results in a cant call .front() on an empty queue. 
Things to consider: The queue is definitely not empty, as before launching the threads i can call .get() and something will be "couted" to the screen.
What works: single threaded works fine. It will wait 20 seconds if the queue is empty, then it will return.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

template <typename StoredType>
class SafeQueue {
public:
    std::condition_variable ready;
    std::mutex queue_lock;

    std::queue<StoredType> safe_queue = {};

    uint8_t empty();
    void put(StoredType& element);
    StoredType get();
};


/* must have it in the header file so linker can see it */

template <typename StoredType>
StoredType SafeQueue<StoredType>::get() {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> condition_lock(queue_lock);

    if (safe_queue.empty()) {


        if (ready.wait_for(condition_lock, std::chrono::seconds(20)) == std::cv_status::timeout) {

            /* timeout was reached, no items left */

            return StoredType();
        }

        /* if a timeout was not hit, but the queue was empty previously this will execute */

        StoredType element = safe_queue.front();

        safe_queue.pop();

        return element;


    }

    else {

        /* not empty, return an element */

        StoredType element = safe_queue.front();

        safe_queue.pop();

        return element;
    }

    /* do not need a return value here since empty HAS to be either true/false */

}

template <typename StoredType>
void SafeQueue<StoredType>::put(StoredType& element) {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> put_guard(queue_lock);

    safe_queue.push(element);

    ready.notify_one();

}

template <typename StoredType>
uint8_t SafeQueue<StoredType>::empty() {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> empty_guard(queue_lock);

    if (safe_queue.size() == 0) {

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i was playing around with it, i dont need/use it anymore. I just edited it

Comment: Ok, now adding elements looks ok. Oddity: `MultiQueue get();` returns a `MultiQueue` that you populate with `return element;`

Comment: yes, the queue is populated with elements of type "MultiQueue" so that would be the return type, and also when i call .front() it will return a type of "MultiQueue"

Comment: Re-think that. If you have a _queue of X_, what would the type returned when you want to extract an element from the queue be? `X` or `queue of X`?

Comment: X, if i have a string filled queue, it will be a string returned.

Comment: Good - now look at the type you do return. (`MultiQueue SafeQueue<MultiQueue>::get()`)

Comment: I am not seeing a problem. If i do SafeQueue<std::string> obj; I can safely say that the queue will hold all strings. MultiQueue in this instance would be std::string

Comment: "_MultiQueue in this instance would be std::string_" - No -  It would be `MultiQueue<std::string>`. Which member function is a user supposed to use to safely extract one element from the queue?

Comment: the get() class func would be used in the worker threads to retrieve one object at a time. ,put() will also be used to add an item back in the worker threads.

Comment: The member function `get` would return a `MultiQueue<std::string>` - not a `std::string`.

Comment: I understand what you mean now, but im not sure how to fix it, to my understanding, MultiQueue is just a placeholder type which is dependent on a user defined type. In visual Studio, by using the auto keyword, it shows that it is infact a string and not a MultiQueue<std::string>

Comment: Make the member function return the type of the elements stored in the queue. I now noticed that the template parameter(s) you've used is a bit odd. If you want to create a queue of `int` the template paramenter(s) you now have will confuse everyone reading the code. You return a `MultiQueue`. Anyone reading that code will get that wrong. Name the template parameter `StoredType` or `T` to make people understand it

Comment: thats what im doing as far as i know (returning the element stored). Are you saying the typename itself is confusing? "MultiQueue"?

Comment: I do. If you store `int` in such a queue and a user reads `MultiQueue get();` the immidiate reaction will be to look for another function to get one single element.

Comment: i see that, i have changed the user defined type to StoredType. I agree it was confusing. I still do not see how it would be locking up with multiple threads

Comment: Good. I haven't tried analyzing the deadlock but now your question is much easier to read so anyone trying to help will understand it better.

Comment: How do you know for sure that get() did time out?  Excluding pushing default constructed StoredType in the queue makes your get() not a very elegant, and your queue unfit for any basic plain type.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a deadlock happening in the `put` method of `SafeQueue<StoredType>`.

It's standard practice to allow the lock_guard to release the mutex *before* calling `condition_variable::notify_one`. Just add a scope level to the lock/push operations:

```
template <typename StoredType>
void SafeQueue<StoredType>::put(StoredType& element) {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> put_guard(queue_lock);
        safe_queue.push(element);
    }
    ready.notify_one();
}
```

Doing this avoids a situation where the notified thread immediately locks again.

Do you need to wait 20s in `get`? That's rather a long timeout. You might want to reduce that to avoid threads waiting a while. You can also simplify the `get` function to include a predicate in the `wait_for` call:

```
template <typename StoredType>
StoredType SafeQueue<StoredType>::get() {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> condition_lock(queue_lock);
    ready.wait_for(condition_lock, std::chrono::seconds(20), [&] { return !safe_queue.empty();  });

    if (safe_queue.empty()) {

        return StoredType();
    }
   
    /* not empty, return an element */

    StoredType element = safe_queue.front();

    safe_queue.pop();

    return element;    
}
```

This has the advantage of protecting against spurious wake-ups with a predicate. Now the wait will only return if the queue is not empty or the timeout occurs.